# Checking to see if a URL is Google

Tags: php

I want to check a URL to see if it is a Google url or not.

I've got this function

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://google.com|i', $url);
}
```

If i try

```
if ( isValidURL('http://google.com/') ){
    echo 'yes its google url';
}
```

It works fine. But if I try

```
if ( isValidURL('http://www.google.com/') ){
    echo 'yes its google url';
}
```

(with `www`) I get an error!

Comment: You get an actual error? What is the error?

Comment: I think the poster simply means his expression doesn't match his regex.

Comment: @Tim not at all, I think Marcus wanted the exact error. Sometimes when doing this, in the browser appears a message like "warning: delimiters of the expression are not correct" or blabla about the regex and you know what to fix.

Comment: yes i mean the expression doesn't match the regex,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, because your regular expression is not ready to handle `www.`

Try

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://(www\.)?google\.com|i', $url);
}
```

Comment: yes i know it's not ready to handle www. ,,, i am not pro in preg_match and i did't know how to add www to the statment, anyway it's know working fine, than you very much

Comment: Beware `http://images.google.com/` or `http://plus.google.com/`. Those too are Google URLs, yet you won't capture them with this. If you don't need them it's fine though.

Comment: @Alaa you did the same thing with https

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to support googles subdomains, try:

```
preg_match('/^https?:\/\/(.+\.)*google\.com(\/.*)?$/is', $url)
```

Comment: i was going to make a new question, to know how to support subdomains! Thanks ccKep for your addition

Answer (score 0):

I like to use PHP's parse_url function to analyse url's. It returns an array with each part of the URL. This way you can be sure you're checking the correct part and it won't be thrown by https or query strings.

```
function isValidUrl($url, $domain_to_check){
       $url = parse_url($url);
       if (strstr($url['host'], $domain_to_search))
            return TRUE;
       return FALSE;
    }
```

Usage:

`isValidUrl("http://www.google.com/q=google.com", "google.com");`